# Django Admin /img not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So iam learning Django at the moment but iam kinda stuck with this problem.

I have a django app called projects, in which iam showing 3 projects (don't mind the lines around everything, i did this to better learn CSS and Bootstrap containers).
[image: Screenshot off my website]

So next feature i tried to implement, is that i can change these projects names etc. in the admin view page. I got it all working and i am seeing the projects.
[image: Screenshot off admin page]

But when iam clicking on a project a get this error.
[image]

So that is the path to the image folder which is defined in my models.py file:
from django.db import models

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.FilePathField(path="/img")
```

And the HTML file

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'projects/app.css' %}">

{% block page_content %}
<h1>Projects</h1>
<div class="row md-4">
{% for project in projects %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-2">
            <img class="project-image" src="{% static 'img/' %}">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ project.title }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ project.description }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.pk %}"
                   class="btn btn-primary">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably need to fix the html image src definition. Can you post the HTML of the img so we can make sure it points to the image, it should be like `src={{ project.image.url }}`

Comment: Added the html file

Comment: did you try `src={{ project.image.url }}`?

Answer (score 0):

you defined the images folder in your model, but you must also do it in your settings.py and urls.py

```
#settings.py
IMAGES_URL = '/images/'  

IMAGES_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')

#urls.py
urlpatterns += static(settings.IMAGES_URL, document_root=settings.IMAGES_ROOT)
```

rember change this too

```
image = models.FilePathField(path="/images")
```